# Is there another way to locate xpath on appium perhaps by using Custom xpaths like how you can with websites?

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium-android

I am trying to do Automation on a proriatory Mobile application on Android real device.

Developers have not added Element ID so the only thing I can use find elements is xpath.

I have managed to launch the app, enter login details and sign in to the app but it cannot find the other xpath of things in the main page.

I found the xpath's using Appium Inspector.

This is the Xpath I am trying to locate and click on.

"//android.widget.SeekBar[@content-desc="Bottom Sheet"]/android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[6]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[1]"

Is there another way to locate xpath perhaps by using Custom xpaths like how you can with websites.

Thanks for your help in advance. :)

Error code presented

Given User logs in to their account # StepDefenitions.VerifyAndLogoutSteps.user_logs_in_to_their_account()
When User checks account page       # StepDefenitions.VerifyAndLogoutSteps.user_checks_account_page()
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [10ca0517-85de-47f1-b30a-2cf866486336, findElement {using=xpath, value=//android.widget.SeekBar[@content-desc="Bottom Sheet"]/android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[6]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView[1]}]
Capabilities

I have tried to use customs paths bellow
driver.findElement(By.xpath("[text()='Account']")).click();
driver.findElement( By.xpath("(//android.view.ViewGroup[text()='Account'])[1]/android.view.ViewGroup")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Account']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[android.widget[contains(text(),'Account')]]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Account']")).click();